# What does "dance with hotdog" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I guess **Snap's investors will be happy in the future because of Snap's partnership with Apple**. Is that correct?

> From my vantage point, Apple’s shoutout Tuesday, which immediately sent SNAP stock soaring 2%, will give Snap some much-needed breathing space. And to the extent that Snap, which arguably introduced AR to the mainstream with its lenses and filters, can leverage Apple’s ARKit to innovate, Snap’s base of disappointing investors will be **dancing with its hotdog** in the quarters and years ahead.

Source: http://www.nasdaq.com/article/Apple-aapl-and-Snap-Snap-friends-or-enemies-cm844775

Comment: It is not a standard collocation but a reference to an internet meme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reference to Snapchats Augmented Reality (AR) filter of a dancing hotdog.  It is apparently one their more popular AR filters.

The article insinuates that Snapchat investors will be so happy they will be dancing throughout the upcoming fiscal quarters, just like their AR hotdog does.  The article you reference provides a link to another article about the hotdog.  I'll include it here:

[AR HotDog](http://www.businessinsider.com/snapchat-hot-dog-2017-7/#snapchats-hot-dog-had-humble-beginnings-appearing-in-a-short-youtube-video-of-a-woman-getting-her-nose-pierced-2)

Comment: Well, there it is.   Not as interesting as I first imagined.  :)